# Set position of a div below that others without absolute positioning?

Tags: css, css-float, absolute

Please visit my website to see my problem: http://amrapps.ir/personal/.

How can i position *the blue div* **below than other divs(the logo,and colorful navigation links)** without absolute positioning? (float:down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
#info {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Due to the div's above having a float, the blue div just moves up there as well. By clearing those floats with `clear: both;`, the div will automatically move down.

---

In addition to your question, here is a solution to your margin-problem, stated in the comments.

To change the space between the blue div and the navigation, change the css as follows:

```
#nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 25px 50px 75px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

As you can see, I used the shorthand way of defining the different margins. You can set the different margins as follows:

`margin: [top] [right] [bottom] [left];`

Any margin you don't define, will take the margin of the opposite value.
That way you can see that I set the top margin to 25px, the right and left margin to 50px and the bottom margin to 75px.

Comment: Thank you it worked but in case that i have no floating elements above(think that colorful navigation links and the logo are positioned absolute) what should i do?

Comment: In that case, the only way to solve it is by adding a padding-top or margin-top to the #info. In that case you also need to be sure that the height of the elements above stay the same. If that is not the case, the only solution is by using javascript.

Comment: Also can i change the space between blue div and the below divs?

Comment: To change the space you'll need to change the bottom margin of the `#nav` div.

Comment: Before asking my question at stackoverflow i tried margin-top but the blue div was at the top and the distance from the browsers's top would increase! I think in other situations Javascript is the only way!

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you an example of the margin-problem you have.